# Can 2D graph state be represented by branching MERA?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

A 2D graph state is a highly entangled state to support general measurement based quantum computation. But its state complexity is relative low. [Branching MERA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1895) represents also a set of low complexity but high entanglement states.

Question: Can 2D graph state (for example on a regular 2D lattice) be represented by branching MERA? Why or why not?

A little bit confused about this problem. I guess the answer is no, otherwise 2D graph state can be classically approximated. But is there a conclusion somewhere?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: On what graph ?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch I would like to check the simple 2D graph state on a regular 2D lattice which is universal for measurement based quantum computation.

Answer (score 1):

Graph states are obtained by starting with all qubits in $|+\rangle$ and applying controlled-Z's between all pairs of qubits on the graph (here, a square lattice). This is in particular a (non-branching) MERA (namely one with only one non-trivial layer - though of course this might depend how precisely you define your 2D MERA network).  Specifically, the lowest layer (green+red) of Fig 5a in https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1895 does the job.

Comment: Sorry I do not get you. 2D graph state can be constructed by a finite length quantum circuit,  can this be transformed into a kind of branching MERA with only a few layers (not only one layer I think since we should not apply two unitary operators on the same bit in MERA) are nontrivial? Since branching MERA can be classically approximated, but 2D graph state can not, so it's not a branching MERA?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. In particular, please specify your precise definition of (branching) MERA in 2D.

Comment: By branching MERA, I follow this paper 'Class of Highly Entangled Many-Body States that can be Efficiently Simulated' of Vidal and other papers from them. Since branching MERA can produce highly entangled states but the complexity seems relatively low. I am wondering if the 2D graph state, which is also computationally simple (generated by a finite size quantum circuit) and highly entangled (at least strong enough to support universal quantum computation). So I am trying to check their relationship. Thanks.

Comment: The lowest layer (green+red) of Fig 5a in said paper (arxiv version) does the job.

Comment: Fig 5? I do not see a Fig 5a in the paper.  1D graph state can be represented by branching MERA by the first green+red layer. But 2D graph state is more complex. If your answer is 'Yes', then do you mean 2D graph state can be classically simulated?

Comment: The arxiv version has a Fig 5.

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks. But according to the paper. branching MERA can be classically simulated, then does this mean the 2D graph state on grid can be classically simulated?  This 2D graph state  is universal for general measurement based quantum computation, do we have a contradiction here? Confused.

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question, explaining where you see a problem?

Comment: I already mentioned this problem in my question. I wondered if the answer is yes, then the 2D graph state can be classically simulated. If this is true, then the local measurement on it is also classically simulatable. Does this mean ALL quantum computation can be classically simulated (2D graph state is universal for quantum computation)?  Maybe I have a misunderstanding about this.

Comment: OK,I will reformulate my problem in a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Please stop these endless series of questions in the comments.